# I put the same size image and video into a parent div separately, but the size of their parent divs are different?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I put the same size image (300x400) and video (300x400) into a parent div separately.

```
<div class="bgimage col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="ol-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <img  src="img"  >
            </div>
</div>
```

and

```
 <div class="bgimage col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="ol-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <video   loop autoplay class="autov">
                  <source src="./resources/img/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the definition in css.

```
.bgimage {
   background-image: url(../img/bg2.png);

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 
    width:100%;
    padding: 30px 50px 30px 50px;
    /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
    background-position: center center;

    /* Background image doesn't tile */
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
    background-size: 100% 100%;

    /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
    background-color: #red;
}
```

But the container of video is slightly larger in height.

Comment: you're also missing a "c" in col-md-6

Comment: @Liquidchrome thanks.

Comment: I asked this question because that on the screen the image and the video has the same size. And their bottom line is at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I have never encountered this with a `video` element so far, but rather with inline images, the fix is the same and very simple:
Add `vertical-align: top;` as a style to your video element, and the additional whitespace will be gone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does  work.The difference reduces but still has a small amount.

Comment: thanks! I think your solution is enough. I generate the video by matlab. And matlab seems change the size of image 'Warning: The video's width and height has been padded to be a multiple of
two as required by the H.264 codec.